# Randomly select image to display on random button in c# unity

Tags: c#, image, button, random, unity-game-engine

I want to display 4 random images, in that one image is correct image. so I picked 1 random image from "correct_caps" folder and rest 3 from another folder. Now, I want to choose random image variables to display that images so that my correct image always change its place.

```
using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;



 public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
  {
 public Image art1;
 public Image art2;
 public Image art3;
 public Image art4;


 public int x;
 public int x1;
 public int x2;
 public int x3;

 public string s;
 public string path;
 public string path1;
 public string path2;
 public string path3;
 public string path4;

 public int cl;
 public int i;


 void Start()
 {


     //selection of correct letter
     cl = Random.Range(1, 26);

     path1 = "Capital Letters/correct_caps/" + cl;
     path = "Capital Letters/" + cl;
     Debug.Log("Load path is " + path1);


     x1 = Random.Range(1, 5);
     path2 = path + "/" + x1;



     x2 = Random.Range(1, 5);
     path3 = path + "/" + x2;
     i = 0;
     while (i == 0)
     {
         if (x1 == x2)
         {

             x2 = Random.Range(1, 5);
             path3 = path + "/" + x2;
             Debug.Log("Load path3 is " + path3);

         }
         else
         {

             Debug.Log("Load path3 is " + path3);
             i++;
         }
     }




     x3 = Random.Range(1, 5);
     path4 = path + "/" + x3;

     i = 0;
     while (i == 0)
     {
         if (x1 == x3 || x2 == x3)
         {
             x3 = Random.Range(1, 5);
             path4 = path + "/" + x3;
             Debug.Log("Load path4 is " + path4);
         }
         else
         {

             Debug.Log("Load path4 is " + path4);
             i++;
         }
     }

  //here I displayed images . But, I want to select art,art1,art2,art3 randomly.

   art.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path1) as Sprite; 
    art1.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path2) as Sprite;
     art2.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path3) as Sprite;
    art3.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path4) as Sprite;  
 }    

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a random number between 1-4, then use the if statment.

```
 Random random = new Random();
 int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 5);
 if (randomNumber ==1)
 {
      art.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path1) as Sprite; 
 }
 if (randomNumber ==2)
 {
      art1.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path2) as Sprite; 
 }
 if (randomNumber ==3)
 {
      art2.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path3) as Sprite; 
 }
 if (randomNumber ==4)
 {
      art3.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path4) as Sprite; 
 }
```

Comment: Here path1 is nothing but my correct letter. Always correct letter (path1) displays on "art" itself is not good idea for game.

Answer (score 0):

To load an image via Resources.Load image must be in the "Resources" folder. you can put it in subfolders if you like.

[Here] (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) is the Documentation